# Geoserver - Add data to PostgreSQL-DB using WFS

Tags: postgresql, geoserver, wfs

We got a new server and decided to upgrade geoserver from 2.14 to 2.21 as we need to run it as a windows server.

When we use our GUI to create the Polygons and safe it using a proxy-script (both the same for the old and new systems) there is a difference we are not able to get rid of.

The old system somehow transfers the incoming "Multisurface"-Geometry to a Multipolygon, but we are not able to replicate this. We are not sure if this is due to geoserver-settings or due to postgres-settings.

This is an excerpt of the geoserverlogs. As far as I can tell it creates Multipolygon-Inserts.

But the postgreslogs show the following insert:

```
2022-11-16 13:54:50 CET FATAL:  tut mir leid, schon zu viele Verbindungen
2022-11-16 13:54:51 CET FEHLER:  Geometry type (MultiSurface) does not match column type (MultiPolygon)
2022-11-16 13:54:51 CET ANWEISUNG:  INSERT INTO (XXX)."f_gbp_f" ("dat_dig","flaeche","deleted","id","the_geom","update_by" ) VALUES ( null,null,0,null,ST_GeomFromText('MULTISURFACE (((398389.37895097 5832615.2430617, 397443.50024903 5830964.2547819, 398698.93925342 5830327.9363825, 399885.58707948 5831944.529073, 399558.82898245 5833784.6930932, 398389.37895097 5832615.2430617)))', 25833),'20202')
    RETURNING *
```

I deleted some of the critical information regardng the features but those were only attributes of type int/str and the name of the db.

Full log for one transaction

```
16 Nov 14:18:04 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] "POST /geoserver/wfs" "" "" "application/xml" 
  Headers:
    Accept: */*
    Expect: 100-continue
    Host: localhost:6081
    Content-Length: 1123
    Content-Type: application/xml request-size: 1123 body: 
<wfs:Transaction xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd"><wfs:Insert><feature:f_gbp_f xmlns:feature="(XXXX)><feature:the_geom><gml:MultiSurface xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:25833"><gml:surfaceMember><gml:Polygon><gml:exterior><gml:LinearRing><gml:posList>402396.46508826 5833698.7041203 399111.68632336 5831325.4084681 403583.11291432 5828883.3216377 404752.56294581 5832099.3092243 403617.50850348 5834059.8578065 402396.46508826 5833698.7041203</gml:posList></gml:LinearRing></gml:exterior></gml:Polygon></gml:surfaceMember></gml:MultiSurface></feature:the_geom><feature:ATTRIBUTE_1>AB</feature:ATTRIBUTE_1><feature:ATTRIBUTE_2>0</feature:ATTRIBUTE_2><feature:ATTRIBUTE_3></feature:ATTRIBUTE_3><feature:ATTRIBUTE_4>107322157000000</feature:ATTRIBUTE_4><feature:deleted>0</feature:deleted><feature:update_by>20202</feature:update_by><feature:ATTRIBUTE_5>107322157000006</feature:ATTRIBUTE_5></feature:f_gbp_f></wfs:Insert></wfs:Transaction>
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped to HandlerExecutionChain with [org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher@612e5cc0] and 2 interceptors
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.requests] - First 4 bytes of XML doc are : 3C ('<') 77 ('w') 66 ('f') 73 ('s')
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geoserver.requests] - Charset detection phase 1. Inferred encoding: UTF-8
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.requests] - Invalid(?) XML declaration: <wfs:T.
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geoserver.requests] - Charset detection phase 2. Charset in XML declaration is `null`.
16 Nov 14:18:04 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'org.geoserver.wfs.xml.entityExpansionLimit' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'org.geoserver.wfs.xml.entityExpansionLimit' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'org.geoserver.wfs.xml.entityExpansionLimit' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'org.geoserver.wfs.xml.entityExpansionLimit' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - schemaLocation found: http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [xsd.impl] - Found override for http://www.opengis.net/wfs: http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd ==> jar:file:/D:/geoserver/GeoServer%202.21/GeoServer/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-wfs-2.21.2.jar!/org/geoserver/wfs/xml/v1_1_0/wfs.xsd
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'PROXY_BASE_URL' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'PROXY_BASE_URL' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'PROXY_BASE_URL' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'PROXY_BASE_URL' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geoserver.wfs] - Locating FeatureSource uri:'http://example.org' name:'f_gbp_f'
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geoserver.wfs] - located FeatureType w/ typeRef 'PostGres_5433:f_gbp_f' and elementName '{http://example.org}f_gbp_f'
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.wfs] - Transaction Insert:org.geoserver.wfs.request.Insert$WFS11@22011cc6
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.wfs] - Use featureValidation to check contents of insert
16 Nov 14:18:04 INFO   [geoserver.gwc] - DataStoreChange: {http://example.org}f_gbp_f TransactionEventType[PreInsert]
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geotools.util] - Error applying the converter class org.geotools.data.util.GeometryConverterFactory$1 on (LayerInfoImpl-3aa05be8:1843303aaf5:-7fe2,class org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry)
org.locationtech.jts.io.ParseException: Unknown geometry type: LayerInfoImpl-3aa05be8
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.WKTReader2.readGeometryTaggedText(WKTReader2.java:418)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.WKTReader2.read(WKTReader2.java:141)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.WKTReader2.read(WKTReader2.java:113)
    at org.geotools.data.util.GeometryConverterFactory$1.convert(GeometryConverterFactory.java:58)
    at org.geotools.util.Converters.convert(Converters.java:150)
    at org.geotools.util.Converters.convert(Converters.java:117)
    at org.geotools.filter.GeometryFilterImpl.getGeometries(GeometryFilterImpl.java:113)
    at org.geotools.filter.GeometryFilterImpl.evaluate(GeometryFilterImpl.java:208)
    at org.geotools.filter.OrImpl.evaluate(OrImpl.java:34)
    at org.geotools.filter.AndImpl.evaluate(AndImpl.java:38)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.DefaultCatalogFacade.lambda$toPredicate$23(DefaultCatalogFacade.java:1208)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CatalogInfoLookup.list(CatalogInfoLookup.java:149)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.DefaultCatalogFacade.iterable(DefaultCatalogFacade.java:1179)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.DefaultCatalogFacade.list(DefaultCatalogFacade.java:1148)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.IsolatedCatalogFacade.list(IsolatedCatalogFacade.java:511)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor305.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.LockingCatalogFacade.invoke(LockingCatalogFacade.java:36)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.list(Unknown Source)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CatalogImpl.list(CatalogImpl.java:2254)
    at org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl.list(SecureCatalogImpl.java:1630)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.AbstractFilteredCatalog.list(AbstractFilteredCatalog.java:933)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.LocalWorkspaceCatalog.list(LocalWorkspaceCatalog.java:588)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.LocalWorkspaceCatalog.list(LocalWorkspaceCatalog.java:569)
    [...]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation  only.
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geotools.util] - Error applying the converter class org.geotools.data.util.GeometryConverterFactory$1 on (LayerInfoImpl-3aa05be8:1843303aaf5:-7fe2,class org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry)
org.locationtech.jts.io.ParseException: Unknown geometry type: LayerInfoImpl-3aa05be8
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.WKTReader2.readGeometryTaggedText(WKTReader2.java:418)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.WKTReader2.read(WKTReader2.java:141)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.WKTReader2.read(WKTReader2.java:113)
    at org.geotools.data.util.GeometryConverterFactory$1.convert(GeometryConverterFactory.java:58)
    at org.geotools.util.Converters.convert(Converters.java:150)
    at org.geotools.util.Converters.convert(Converters.java:117)
    at org.geotools.filter.GeometryFilterImpl.getGeometries(GeometryFilterImpl.java:113)
    at org.geotools.filter.GeometryFilterImpl.evaluate(GeometryFilterImpl.java:208)
    at org.geotools.filter.OrImpl.evaluate(OrImpl.java:34)
    at org.geotools.filter.AndImpl.evaluate(AndImpl.java:38)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.DefaultCatalogFacade.lambda$toPredicate$23(DefaultCatalogFacade.java:1208)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CatalogInfoLookup.list(CatalogInfoLookup.java:149)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.DefaultCatalogFacade.iterable(DefaultCatalogFacade.java:1179)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.DefaultCatalogFacade.list(DefaultCatalogFacade.java:1148)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.IsolatedCatalogFacade.list(IsolatedCatalogFacade.java:511)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor305.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [...]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation  only.
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - SELECT "gid","ATTRIBUTE_4","ATTRIBUTE_5","ATTRIBUTE_2","ATTRIBUTE_3","ATTRIBUTE_1","dat_dig","flaeche","deleted","id",encode(ST_AsEWKB("the_geom"), 'base64') as "the_geom","update_by" FROM XXXX."f_gbp_f" WHERE 0 = 1
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting ATTRIBUTE_4 to 107322157000000
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 0 to 107322157000000
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting ATTRIBUTE_5 to 107322157000006
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 1 to 107322157000006
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting ATTRIBUTE_2 to 0
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 2 to 0
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting ATTRIBUTE_3 to 
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 3 to 
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting ATTRIBUTE_1 to AB
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 4 to AB
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting dat_dig to null
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 5 to null
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting flaeche to null
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 6 to null
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting deleted to 0
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 7 to 0
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting id to null
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 8 to null
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting the_geom to MULTIPOLYGON (((402396.46508826 5833698.7041203, 399111.68632336 5831325.4084681, 403583.11291432 5828883.3216377, 404752.56294581 5832099.3092243, 403617.50850348 5834059.8578065, 402396.46508826 5833698.7041203)))
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 9 to MULTIPOLYGON (((402396.46508826 5833698.7041203, 399111.68632336 5831325.4084681, 403583.11291432 5828883.3216377, 404752.56294581 5832099.3092243, 403617.50850348 5834059.8578065, 402396.46508826 5833698.7041203)))
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting update_by to 20202
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Setting 10 to 20202
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [data.jdbc] - exporting LiteralExpression
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - Inserting new feature: INSERT INTO XXXX."f_gbp_f" ( "ATTRIBUTE_4","ATTRIBUTE_5","ATTRIBUTE_2","ATTRIBUTE_3","ATTRIBUTE_1","dat_dig","flaeche","deleted","id","the_geom","update_by" ) VALUES ( '107322157000000','107322157000006','0','','AB',null,null,0,null,ST_GeomFromText('MULTISURFACE (((402396.46508826 5833698.7041203, 399111.68632336 5831325.4084681, 403583.11291432 5828883.3216377, 404752.56294581 5832099.3092243, 403617.50850348 5834059.8578065, 402396.46508826 5833698.7041203)))', 25833),'20202')
16 Nov 14:18:04 ERROR  [geoserver.wfs] - Transaction failed
org.geoserver.wfs.WFSTransactionException: Error performing insert: Error inserting features
    at org.geoserver.wfs.InsertElementHandler.execute(InsertElementHandler.java:239)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.Transaction$BatchManager.runAggregated(Transaction.java:758)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.Transaction$BatchManager.run(Transaction.java:701)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.Transaction.execute(Transaction.java:296)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.Transaction.transaction(Transaction.java:95)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.DefaultWebFeatureService.transaction(DefaultWebFeatureService.java:154)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.geoserver.ows.util.RequestObjectLogger.invoke(RequestObjectLogger.java:51)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy122.transaction(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [...]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error inserting features
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.insert(JDBCDataStore.java:1862)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCInsertFeatureWriter.flush(JDBCInsertFeatureWriter.java:130)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCInsertFeatureWriter.write(JDBCInsertFeatureWriter.java:102)
    at org.geotools.data.InProcessLockingManager$1.write(InProcessLockingManager.java:302)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureStore.addFeature(ContentFeatureStore.java:295)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureStore.addFeatures(ContentFeatureStore.java:250)
    at org.vfny.geoserver.global.GeoServerFeatureStore.addFeatures(GeoServerFeatureStore.java:63)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.InsertElementHandler.execute(InsertElementHandler.java:205)
    ... 131 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FEHLER: Geometry type (MultiSurface) does not match column type (MultiPolygon)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:490)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:408)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:329)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:315)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeUpdate(PgStatement.java:1248)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeUpdate(PgStatement.java:1230)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingStatement.java:323)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingStatement.java:323)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.insertNonPS(JDBCDataStore.java:2042)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.insert(JDBCDataStore.java:1858)
    ... 138 more
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
16 Nov 14:18:04 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: transaction
    service = WFS
    version = 1.1.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:6081/geoserver/
    group[0] = wfs:insert=net.opengis.wfs.impl.InsertElementTypeImpl@1482e830 (feature: [SimpleFeatureImpl:f_gbp_f=[SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: ATTRIBUTE_4<ATTRIBUTE_4 id=fid--3e85d437_1848053191b_-7feb>=107322157000000, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: ATTRIBUTE_5<ATTRIBUTE_5 id=fid--3e85d437_1848053191b_-7feb>=107322157000006, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: ATTRIBUTE_2<ATTRIBUTE_2 id=fid--3e85d437_1848053191b_-7feb>=0, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: ATTRIBUTE_3<ATTRIBUTE_3 id=fid--3e85d437_1848053191b_-7feb>=, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: ATTRIBUTE_1<ATTRIBUTE_1 id=fid--3e85d437_1848053191b_-7feb>=AB, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: dat_dig<dat_dig id=fid--3e85d437_1848053191b_-7feb>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: flaeche<flaeche id=fid--3e85d437_1848053191b_-7feb>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: deleted<deleted id=fid--3e85d437_1848053191b_-7feb>=0, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: id<id id=fid--3e85d437_1848053191b_-7feb>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: the_geom<the_geom id=fid--3e85d437_1848053191b_-7feb>=MULTIPOLYGON (((402396.46508826 5833698.7041203, 399111.68632336 5831325.4084681, 403583.11291432 5828883.3216377, 404752.56294581 5832099.3092243, 403617.50850348 5834059.8578065, 402396.46508826 5833698.7041203))), SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: update_by<update_by id=fid--3e85d437_1848053191b_-7feb>=20202]], handle: null, idgen: <unset>, inputFormat: <unset>, srsName: null)
    insert[0]:
        feature[0] = SimpleFeatureImpl:f_gbp_f=[SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: ATTRIBUTE_4<ATTRIBUTE_4 id=fid--3e85d437_1848053191b_-7feb>=107322157000000, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: ATTRIBUTE_5<ATTRIBUTE_5 id=fid--3e85d437_1848053191b_-7feb>=107322157000006, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: ATTRIBUTE_2<ATTRIBUTE_2 id=fid--3e85d437_1848053191b_-7feb>=0, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: ATTRIBUTE_3<ATTRIBUTE_3 id=fid--3e85d437_1848053191b_-7feb>=, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: ATTRIBUTE_1<ATTRIBUTE_1 id=fid--3e85d437_1848053191b_-7feb>=AB, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: dat_dig<dat_dig id=fid--3e85d437_1848053191b_-7feb>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: flaeche<flaeche id=fid--3e85d437_1848053191b_-7feb>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: deleted<deleted id=fid--3e85d437_1848053191b_-7feb>=0, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: id<id id=fid--3e85d437_1848053191b_-7feb>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: the_geom<the_geom id=fid--3e85d437_1848053191b_-7feb>=MULTIPOLYGON (((402396.46508826 5833698.7041203, 399111.68632336 5831325.4084681, 403583.11291432 5828883.3216377, 404752.56294581 5832099.3092243, 403617.50850348 5834059.8578065, 402396.46508826 5833698.7041203))), SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: update_by<update_by id=fid--3e85d437_1848053191b_-7feb>=20202]
        idgen = GenerateNew
        inputFormat = text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1
    releaseAction = ALL
16 Nov 14:18:04 INFO   [geoserver.servlets] - OutputStream was successfully aborted.
16 Nov 14:18:04 INFO   [geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.wfs.WFSException: Error performing insert: Error inserting features
    at org.geoserver.wfs.response.TransactionResponse.v_1_1(TransactionResponse.java:196)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.response.TransactionResponse.write(TransactionResponse.java:62)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.response(Dispatcher.java:1018)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1043)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsync.service(ServletHolder.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1656)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.ows.HTTPHeadersCollector.doFilter(HTTPHeadersCollector.java:48)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:190)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:43)
    [...]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'PROXY_BASE_URL' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'PROXY_BASE_URL' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'PROXY_BASE_URL' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'PROXY_BASE_URL' to be unset
16 Nov 14:18:04 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] "POST /geoserver/wfs" took 47ms
16 Nov 14:18:04 DEBUG  [filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: Please share the full stack trace, including all of the "caused by" bits.

Comment: @AndreaAime I added a bigger part of the lgos, i had to remove some parts due to the maximum length for the body of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently our old Postgres/Postgis-Combination was not working out with the newer geoserver-release.
We decided to downgrade Geoserver to 2.15 and it works like a charm again.